# Pipe a lot of files to stdin, extract first columns, then combine those in a new file

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, paste, cut

Suppose we have these two files:

```
$ cat ABC.txt 
ABC DEF

$ cat PQR.txt 
PQR XTZ
```

And we want to form a *new* file with the 1st column of each file. This can be achieved by:

```
$ paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 ABC.txt) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 PQR.txt )
ABC PQR
```

But I want to use this with tons of files in the input, not only ABC.txt and PQR.TXT, but a lot of them.  How we can generalize this situation to pass each file in the collection to **cut** and then pass all the outputs to **paste** (I know that this may be done better with **awk** but I want to know how to solve this using this approach).

---

Edit 1

I have discovered a dirty, dirty way of doing this:

```
$ str='';  for i in *.txt; \
           do    str="${str} <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 ${i})"; \
           done ; \
  str="paste -d ' ' $str"; \
  eval $str
```

But please, free my soul with an answer that does not involve going to *Computer Science Hell*.

Edit 2

Each file can have n rows, if this matters.

Comment: do you have only one row for each file?

Comment: No, each file have n rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process substitution `<(somecommand)` doesn't pipe to stdin, it actually opens a pipe on a separate file descriptor, e.g. 63, and passes in `/dev/fd/63`. When this "file" is opened, the kernel* duplicates the fd instead of opening a real file.

We can do something similar by opening a bunch of file descriptors and then passing them to the command:

```
# Start subshell so all files are automatically closed
(
  fds=()
  n=0
  # Open a new fd for each process subtitution
  for file in ./*.txt
  do
    exec {fds[n++]}< <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 "$file")
  done

  # fds now contain a list of fds like 12 14
  # prepend "/dev/fd/" to all of them
  parameters=( "${fds[@]/#//dev/fd/}" )

  paste -d ' ' "${parameters[@]}"
)
```

`{var}< file` is bash's syntax for dynamic file descriptor assignment.  like `var=4; exec 4< file;` but without having to hardcode the 4 and instead let bash pick a free file descriptor. `exec` opens it in the current shell.

* Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and XNU/OSX anyways. This is not POSIX, but neither is `<(..)`

Comment: Nicely done; it's worth mentioning that the `{var}` method of defining file descriptors requires Bash 4.1+.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! By the way i suppose you mean `var=4; exec 4< file;`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

After a closer look, I see that @that-other-guy's answer is awesome, but here also is another dirty dirty way that's roughly the same under the hood.

```
eval "paste -d' ' "$(find *.txt -printf " <(cut -d' ' -f1 '%f')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given space delimited input files, and provided ':' is a safe delimiter, (i.e. if there are no colons in the input), this **paste** to **sed** one-liner works:

```
paste -d':' *.txt | sed 's/ [^:]*$//;s/ [^:]*:*/ /g;s/://g'
```

(POSIX, with no **eval**, **exec**, **bash***isms*, subshells, or loops.)

Comment: @that-other-guy's and my answers are ~50x as fast as this (tested with 3 10,000,000-line .txt files).

Comment: @webb, that's cool, but didn't the OP say he was testing a lot of little files, rather than a few big files?  A benchmark for 10,000,000 3-line text files might be more relevant.

Comment: interesting point. your answer is 50x faster for 2000 single-line files, e.g., 40,000 files/second vs 800 files/second for @that-other-guy's and my answers! additionally, all three answers fail completely for e.g. 3000 (or more) files.

Comment: @webb, that's a surprise, 50x on _opposite_ sides... a good illustration of algorithms for file length vs. file size.  If time permits, do provide more detail in what way all three answers "fail completely" at some point.  Did they slow down, return wrong answers, or what?

Comment: they fail because of too many open files (yours) or file descriptors (mine & @that-other-guy's).

Comment: After trying it with several hundred thousand files, and observing this answer to fail, I believe it failed because of the '*' exceeded the maximum command line length.  Also _ext4_  bogs down something awful with that many small files.  Am currently making 10,000,000 files on a _reiserfs_ partition, to see what's possible there.  Without a wildcard '\*', it looks like `find` might be the best substitute.